# Retrieving messages shared by the sender and receiver - chat mongodb, express, react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have two collections `students` and `teachers` in the mongodb database. Below is an example structure of a conversation between a student and a teacher. In the student and teacher object, I have an array of `messages` containing objects that are messages, and `receiver` and `sender` containing the `id` of the person sending and receiving the message. I am asking for advice on what function to create to download common messages for the sender and receiver and display them either on the sender's or the receiving side, depending on who sent. On the left side of the message if it was sent by the student, on the right side if it was sent by the teacher. Anyone have material explaining how to do this??

**Students**

```
{
    "_id": { "$oid": "600333" },
    "name": "MMMMMM",
    "surname": "xxxxx",
    "email": "mar@gmail.com",
    "role": "student",
    "messages": [
      {
        "contentInfo": {
          "viewed": false,
          "msg": "22222222ghjk",
          "createdAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "" } }
        },
        "_id": { "$oid": "" },
        "receiver": { "$oid": "5fea6e09" }
      },
      {
        "contentInfo": {
          "viewed": false,
          "msg": "heloooo",
          "createdAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "" } }
        },
        "_id": { "$oid": "" },
        "receiver": { "$oid": "5fea6e09" }
      },
      {
        "contentInfo": {
          "viewed": false,
          "msg": "dfdfdf",
          "createdAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "" } }
        },
        "_id": { "$oid": "" },
        "receiver": { "$oid": "600333" }
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Teachers**

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "5fea6e09" },
  "isActiveTutor": false,
  "youtubeUrlId": "",
  "name": "rrrr",
  "surname": "rrrrr",
  "email": "u@gmail.com",
  "initials": "",
  "role": "tutor",
  "createdAt": { "$date": "" },
  "updatedAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "" } },
  "messages": [
    {
      "contentInfo": {
        "viewed": false,
        "msg": "22222222ghjk"
        "createdAt": { "$date": "" }
      },
      "_id": { "$oid": "" },
      "sender": { "$oid": "600333" }
    },
    {
      "contentInfo": {
        "viewed": false,
        "msg": "heloooo",
        "createdAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "" } }
      },
      "_id": { "$oid": "" },
      "sender": { "$oid": "600333" }
    },
    {
      "contentInfo": {
        "viewed": false,
        "msg": "dfdfdf",
        "createdAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "" } }
      },
      "_id": { "$oid": "" },
      "sender": { "$oid": "5fea6e09" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is correct the sample data for student and teachers? because in the "msg": "22222222ghjk" and "msg": "heloooo", sender is "600333", so who is the reciver? You get an error when you save all the messages in one document and the chat size is more than 16 MB

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi it's only 'fake' structure. In this case about you Ask. Sender is student, receiver is tutor. In according to you, how IT should look like?

Answer (score 4):

I would personally recommend not to save the messages nested on the object, Imagine how quickly the scale on this can explode for a single teacher with many many students.

For a toy example this is fine but for an actual app you should never do this.

The more common approach is one of the following two:

1. (My recommendation) is to have a separate collection for messages, each message will be with the same structure:

```
{ 
  created_time: Date,
  sender_id: ObjectId,
  receiver_id: ObjectId,
  message: string
}
```

With an index built on both `sender_id` and `receiver_id` with `created_time` this is the most scaleable solution, you can also "retire" old messages into a different collection based on your needs, for example for a chat feature you can fetch the last x messages between the two and allow loading of more, this can be easily done with `skip` and `limit`.

2. Create a "conversation" collection, a conversation will hold nested messages in a similar way to the student / teacher, the advantage of this over your current structure is exactly as I explained before, a teacher with 30 students will have it's messages array explode, making querying / fetching data from him slow. this allows better management of that but this solution is also capped to an extent.

Comment: Do you recommend that put all messages { 
  created_time: Date,
  sender_id: ObjectId,
  receiver_id: ObjectId,
  message: string
} in one collection 'messages'?  How can I put "retire' old messages in another collection. I have to delete from one collecton and put in another for example 30 days? But later I will have to fetch messages from two collections?

Comment: The purpose of retiring or archiving is done in many places, the goal is to maintain a lean fast collection with fast queries under the premise that messages from let's say a year ago are not relevant / not accessed often. Yes if you do this you will have to manage another collection. i merely suggested it as an option also it is probably not required by your app which probably won't reach super scale.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://getstream.io/blog/how-to-create-a-chat-app-with-angular-9/

This is an Angular blog, but since you already have the message history, you can use the `html` and `css` to replicate the chatting feature with messages on both sides depending on who send the message.

Basically, you can `copy-paste` the code and just modify this part:

```
<li class="message" *ngFor="let message of messages">
              <div
                *ngIf="
                  message.user.id !== currentUser.me.id;
                  then incoming_msg;
                  else outgoing_msg
                "
              ></div>
              <ng-template #incoming_msg>
                <div class="incoming_msg">
                  <div class="incoming_msg_img">
                    <img
                      src="https://i.imgur.com/k2PZLZa.png"
                      alt="User avatar"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="received_msg">
                    <div class="received_withd_msg">
                      <p>{{ message.text }}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template #outgoing_msg>
                <div class="outgoing_msg">
                  <div class="sent_msg">
                    <p>{{ message.text }}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ng-template>
</li>
```

What this part does is that it iterate over the list of messages and check should the message go on the left or on the right side.

Let's say that if the `Student` is logged in, he can choose to open his conversation with some `Teacher`. In that case you will need to get all the messages between that particular `Student` and than particular `Teacher`. You can create an endpoint that will return the message history of the current user and selected interlocutor. For that let's create an endpoint that will take `current_user_id`, `current_user_role` and `interlocutor_id` and based on that will return the `message-history`.

The endpoint can look like this:

```
router.get('/message-history', (req, res, next) => {

  const { current_user_id, current_user_role, interlocutor_id } = req.query;

  if (current_user_role === 'student') {
    Students.findById(current_user_id).then((student) => {
      let messages = student.messages.filter((message) => (message.sender == interlocutor_id || message.receiver== interlocutor_id));
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, messages: messages })
    }).catch((error) => {
      res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'User can not be found.' })
    })
  } else {
    Teachers.findById(current_user_id).then((teacher) => {
      let messages = student.messages.filter((message) => (message.sender == interlocutor_id || message.receiver== interlocutor_id));
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, messages: messages })
    }).catch((error) => {
      res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'User can not be found.' })
    })
  }

});
```

Now when you have the `message-history` array you can divide the messages. If the message has the property `receiver` you can put it on one side, and if it has property `sender` you can put it on other side.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I have two collections `tutors` and` students` (I pasted code examples). How do I create a query in `express, mongodb` to retrieve these messages?

Comment: I updated the answer. Check if that works for you.

Comment: Can we tak on the chat?

Comment: What's the best approach to store massages in database mongodb? I have messages in object teacher and student. is it good approach?